# In Django APP the static file CSS is getting loaded but it is not showing any effect on the page?

Tags: python, css, django, static, django-staticfiles

Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.5

I am able to load a image in my page but when i try to load a css file , i think it also gets loaded but it is not showing any effect, because in firebug, no content is showing inside the css file. I am inserting an image of firebug
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9awX.jpg)

the codes are 
**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

```
<head>
    <title>Rango</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}"/>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> {{msg}} </h1>
    <a href='/rango/about'>about</a>
    <img src="{% static 'images/background.jpg' %} " alt="my image">
</body>
```

**css page**

```
body {color:red;
```

}

**settings.py file**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
static_path=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    static_path,
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Edit1:  I have also tried `{% load static %}` and `{% load staticfiles %}` but none of them worked.

Comment: What happens if you do just `{% load static %}` so without the 'from staticfiles'

Answer (score 0):

**Do these changes.**

**1.** On top of your html page, add `{% load staticfiles %}`. **Before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`**  
 **2.** In your application directory, make sure there is a folder called static. (Which holds all the css,imgs,js files)
 **3.** In you settings.py in your project folder, 
    `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` 
 **4.** When you call the CSS sheet in your html page, do it like this:`enter code here`

**Note** 
I cannot tell you the exact folder names as you haven't displayed your folder structure. But i hope this helps.

If you want to get a more idea of how it should work regarding folder structures, check thi:. 
[Github Django Open source Blog app](https://github.com/geethpw/Blog-App-Python-2.7-Django-)